# Resolve domain names to IP's based on physical adapter

Tags: dns, iptables, dhcp, ip, hosts

**System Configuration**

1. eth0 NIC to the LAN/WAN/Internet (working, don't want to mess with it)
2. eth1 NIC
3. eth2 NIC

**Objectives**

1. Assign a static IP to `eth1` and `eth2` and assign IPs (DHCP) on separate subnets to nodes on each adapter.
2. Resolve and forward requests made to `mydomainexample.com` to the respective IP of each adapter they came in on.  Requests will come in on an uncommon port and be directed to the same port (`/etc/hosts` or a true DNS server).

**Progress**

DHCP Attempts Thus Far: Making edits to `/etc/dhcp/dhcp.conf` I am confident the IP settings are okay but want to confirm the appropriate DNS and domain settings.

```
subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
range 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.1;
interface eth1;
#  option domain-name-servers ns1.internal.example.org;
#}

subnet 192.168.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
range 192.168.2.1 192.168.2.1;
interface eth2;
#  option domain-name-servers ns1.internal.example.org;
#}
```

For the DNS resolution and forwarding it appears `/etc/hosts` edits and or iptables configurations are in order.

Something along the lines of this?:

```
iptables -i eth1 -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --sport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.0:11111
```

Also requests will be targeting a domain name, so should I be first redirecting to a DNS (or `/etc/hosts/`) on another IP that then resolves that domain to the adapter IP address?